# iPhone program immediately exits when loading a View from an NIB

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, uibutton

The app in question is a simple sample program. In my view controller header, I have the button instantiated as such:

```
@interface ObscurelyNamedViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton *yoButton;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *yoButton;

- (IBAction)yoButtonPressed:(id)sender;
```

yoButtonPressed: is implemented as such:

```
[yoButton setTitle: @"I said 'yo', jammit!" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
// repeat for other button states
.
.
.
```

In Interface Builder, I have connected the Touch Up Inside event of the UIButton to the yoButtonPressed method in the File's Owner of the `ObscurelyNamedViewController` to recognize the touch. In return, I have connected the outlet of the File's Owner back to the yoButton, so as to enable the updating of it's title.

When I build and run, I get no errors, but nothing displays and the app immediately quits. The only other thing living in IB is a UIImage view. Am I missing something or have I wired something incorrectly?

**EDIT:** In the console, I see the following message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "BradiiCaliiViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

Comment: When it quit, you should have gotten a message in the Console.  There is so much that could be wrong -- need the message to help

Comment: Had this problem again, but this time could not connect the view outlet. Resolved and posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227332/view-outlet-not-available-to-files-owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Moved from comment on Lou Franco answer:*

BradiiCaliiViewController complains that it doesn't have a view even after NIB was loaded. You have to connect view outlet of File's Owner to your view in BradiiCaliiViewController's XIB.

Answer (score 1):

This likely has nothing to do with that action.  You said, "nothing displays and the app immediately quits", which means that the action was never sent.

Need your message from the Console, but check

1. Did you use initWithNibName?  If so, did you get the name exactly right?
2. Are you doing anything with Outlets in init?  You should not -- and do it in viewDidLoad.

Knowing the message in your console will help us give you the real answer though.

Edit: based on your console message

1. Double-click .xib file to go to IB
2. Click on File's Owner
3. Go to Connections Inspector
4. The view outlet is not set (right?) -- drag the circle to the view icon in the Document Window.

(I am sorry, but I don't have IB in front of me -- this is from memory -- look around for the view outlet in connection inspectors if I am wrong about the exact location)

Comment: Ah, well this might be helpful... Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "BradiiCaliiViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: BradiiCaliiViewController complains that it doesn't have a view even after NIB was loaded. You have to connect `view` outlet of File's Owner to your view in BradiiCaliiViewController's XIB.

Comment: @hoha: Promote comment to answer. Fixed in IB and that did the trick. ;). Thanks to both!

Comment: @hoha -- just add an answer with your information -- didn't notice this comment when I updated my answer.